# LazyLoad loading all images on load

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I can't imagine how this just started happening, it's been working fine for months...

http://www.lizhess.com/shop/

Watch your net tab in chrome/ff - it loads 250+ image requests after a second of being on the page... it says that jquery initiates these requests...

It's almost as if something in LL is confused about which images are visible... I've tried many options to no avail.

Using this LL : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
and using this code:

```
jQuery("img.lazy").lazyload({
effect: "fadeIn",
  effectspeed: 200,
  failure_limit: Math.max(jQuery("img").length - 1, 0)
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's the `event` setting.  By [default](https://raw.github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.js) it is set to `scroll`, and it looks like it loads all of the images on scroll.

In the console if you do:

```
jQuery('img.lazy').attr('src', ''); //Reset the images
jQuery('img.lazy').lazyload({event: 'hover'}); //Rebind our own
```

you'll notice that it works correctly on hover now.  So I believe it's just the `scroll` event causing issues.  The strange thing is that I believe the `threshold` setting should take care of this, but I've never used the plugin, so I'm not entirely sure.

Still, I hope this at least points you in the right direction, and you may be able to either change the event, or stagger which `img` elements you lazyLoad.

**Update**

If you do something similar with the unveil plugin (in the console), it actually seems to work properly (in Firefox, without placeholders):

```
jQuery('img.lazy').attr('src', '');
jQuery('img.lazy').unveil(); //Images will now load as they are scrolled to
```

So perhaps you could try delaying the call to unveil.

Comment: This is actually pretty much as I've figured already :/ - I did try the threshold option, didn't seem to make any difference...

I NEED the system to work via the scroll event. It was working, loading only visible images, and then loading more as you scrolled down.

But then it just stopped. Can't figure... guess i'll be debugging this more tomorrow :) Thanks for the suggestions there.

Comment: One further test, I pulled the lazyload initialization script out entirely and loaded the page, of course no images loaded. I then ran the init script in the console, nothing happened (good sign) - I then scrolled in the main window.. POW all images load at once (and a goods couple seconds of hard browser lock-up) ... I did recently upgrade chrome... I wonder if there is a bug here now?

Comment: Another thing to note, I cracked open LL - theres a helper function/selector $("img:below-the-fold") - running this returns nothing... however running it on his demo- [link](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html) does return some elements... so this means LL is somehow seeing the WHOLE window as "visible" images...

Comment: Also interesting, this [link](https://github.com/luis-almeida/unveil/blob/master/jquery.unveil.js) has the exact same problem... Something is really messed up on this page somehow :/

Comment: For the meantime i've done this:

`setTimeout(function() {jQuery("img").unveil();}, 1);`
In the ready()

It's just a temp fix, but this makes the page basically load fully, then the images load via JS a millisecond later... the user doesn't see much of a difference because the top 9 images in view load very quickly.

Comment: @godofleet I've updated my answer with an update for the new plugin.

Comment: It seems to me that I have this problem too. I use unveil, and in chrome it loads every single image as soon as the initial load is done (and hangs in the GUI while loading). It works fine in firefox. I do manipulate a bit with the scroll. Do anyone have a fix for this, or is it still kind of unsolved?

Answer (score 2):

[toopola](https://github.com/tuupola/lazyload/issues/343):

> Your images are most likely all in the viewport when the page loads. This happens for example when HTML does not set the dimensions of the image.

That was the problem for me. Had to set minimal dimensions to the images so they are not all 0px tall before they load.